# If Condtion in mysql where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table named `content` with field `id`, `namew`, `publish_date`, `unpublish_date`

`publish_date` and `unpublish_date` both are can be `null`

Now I want to select data if `publish_date is not null` then `publish_date <= CURDATE()`

I try with this query

```
select * 
from content
where if(publish_date is not null, publish_date  <= CURDATE(),'')
```

But I dont know what to put in else condition. Coz I need only if condition not else condition

Comment: And if `publish_date` is null then what to select ?

Comment: If you want to include rows with a null publish date then `WHERE IF(publish_date is not null, publish_date  <= CURDATE(),0)` or just `WHERE IFNULL(publish_date, CURDATE())<=CURDATE()` although wrapping the attribute in a function means that you won't be able to use any available indexes. If you do have an index on publish_date then `WHERE publish_date IS NULL OR publish_date<=CURDATE()`

Comment: You probably don't need the `if` function here if you want to test for not null and current or earlier date...  It is unusual to see an `if` function in a where clause because `where` allows `and`, `or`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write mutually excluding conditions:

```
select * 
from content 
where publish_date is null
   or publish_date <= CURDATE()
```

Comment: @nur-uddin Have you try this answer? I think this answer acceptable and solve your problems.

Comment: This says to include all rows where the publish date is null or the publish date is today or earlier.  Why include dates where the publish date is null? The poster has not explained what they want, exactly, but if this were for selecting blog/news articles it would probably omit the nulls as being unpublished articles.

Comment: @Paul: well, as you can see from the post logic, there should be no condition in case `publish_date is null`, so the records should be included, _otherwise_, if I'm wrong, OP can simply remove unnecessary `publish_date is null` condition.

Comment: @notulysses Looks like I stand corrected, by the comment under the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

Hi i didn't think where accept condition but you can did it on select

```
SELECT IF(publish_date is not null, publish_date, '') as alias
FROM content
WHERE alias != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from content where publish_date is not null && publish_date  <= CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the `else` part then just pass `false` to it.

```
select * from content where if(publish_date is not null, publish_date  <= CURDATE(), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this following query: If you want nothing in else condition just put `0` (FALSE).

```
select * 
from content 
WHERE IF(publish_date is not null, publish_date <= CURDATE(), 0)
```

> Assuming that if publish_date is null nothing to check.

[**Details**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)